# svn Error: a versioned directory of the same name already exists

Tags: svn, windows-7, tortoisesvn

I am trying to switch my local folder from Branch to Trunk. I get the following error.

```
Failed to add directory 'Drive:\Path\To\The\Directory'
a versioned directory of the same name already exists
```

What is the resolution for this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You often see this if you have a situation where you've created a directory on the branch (even I think if you haven't checked it in), but meanwhile someone has also created a directory of the same name on the trunk.  So when you switch from branch to trunk it's trying to check out trunk's version of the directory, but it can't because it already exists and so it doesn't want to trash your version of it.

EDIT:

The best way to resolve this is to rename this directory in your working copy then update.  After the update you can decide whether you need to copy the contents into the newly created directory.

EDIT2:

There isn't a good way of SVN resolving this automatically. It sounds like you have created this folder in your working copy (which is currently checked out on the branch) while someone else has created a folder of this name on the trunk. When you switch it's trying to create the new directory, but it can't because you've already got one.  I maintain that the *only* way of dealing with this is to rename the directory temporarily, then switch and then compare the contents of both directories to see if there are extra files you need to add or merge.

Comment: This answer fails to give a proper resolution for the issue. Are you aware of how to solve this? (I currently running into this problem, and my best fix is to do a clean checkout, which is awfully time consuming)

Comment: I have a situation where renaming isn't a good option.   Is there a way to repair it?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that \Path\To\The\Directory doesn't exist in the branch, but does exist in the trunk. Newly added to the trunk maybe?  When you switch, SVN thinks it should be adding it to your local directory, as it's not (supposed to be) in the branch that you're switching from. But it's there anyway. This could be a result of a prior switch without a proper checkout. i.e. you did this switch before, and then when you switched from the trunk back to the branch, you didn't clean up the crud.  so now the leftover directory is present, and it doen't expect to see it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `Path/To/The/Directory` doesn't exist in your current branch, but it does exist in trunk?

Another thing that might be the problem is when the SVN server is running a case-sensitive OS (*nix, for example), and you are using Windows. In that case, the SVN server will consider:

```
Path/To/The/Directory
Path/To/The/directory
```

as two different directories. This usually happens when someone does a case change on the directory name.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is to use `svn switch` with the `--force` flag.

For example, I saw the error after switching to a branch, when I switched back to trunk. This solved my issues:

```
svn switch --force ^/trunk
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this error while leaving the directory in place, I found the following technique worked:

- SVN switch the directory to the correct path in the repository (if it is not pointing there already).
- Move the .svn hidden folder inside the directory to some safe location (your desktop).
- SVN Cleanup and Update the parent directory. *The Update may result in the same error on some subdirectory. Ignore this.*
- A new .svn hidden folder will have been created inside the directory. Move the original .svn hidden folder back inside the directory, overwriting existing contents of the new .svn folder.
  *I don't recall if I did this because of some error, or as a hunch…anyway it seemed to do the trick.*
- SVN update the directory again.
- Voila!

Note that at least one time on one system, this trick resulted in all subdirectories/files showing ?. Deleting a .svn folder from a subdirectory and Cleaning/Updating the parent again did the trick.

Not sure what voodoo this is, but I committed changes and updated various systems afterwards and they all seem happy.

FYI I got to this state due to an unusual situation:

/foo was an svn:external to /newfoo/bar, and this arrangement needed to be undone so /newfoo/bar was moved and renamed as /foo.

- I deleted the svn:external property on / pointing to /foo, and committed.
- I used TortoiseSVN's repository browser to first move /newfoo/bar to /bar, then rename /bar to /foo.
- SVN Update on my local copy first resulted in the error message that /foo was pointing at /newfoo/bar when /foo existed (or somesuch).
- I SVN switched /foo to the new path /foo
- Now SVN Update resulted in the "versioned directory of the same name already exists" error.